# Number Guessing Game Python 3.8

Tags: python

A random number between 1 and 6, this represents a roll of a dice. The random number becomes the number of allowed guesses from the user. I cannot get the dice number to be same as amount of guesses allowed.

This is what I have so far:

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 100)
player_name = input("Hello, What's your name?")
number_of_guesses = 0
print('okay! '+ player_name+ ' I am guessing a number between 1 and 100:')
min_value = 1
max_value = 6
print(random.randint(min_value, max_value))
while number_of_guesses < 5:
   guess = int(input())
   number_of_guesses += 1
   if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low")
   if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high")
   if guess == number:
        break
   if guess == number:
        print("You guessed the number in " + str(number_of_guesses) + " tries!")
   else:
        print("You did not guess the number, the number was " + str(number))
```

Comment: You just print `random.randint(min_value, max_value)` but never use this amount of max guesses. You could save it to a variable and instead of `while number_of_guesses < 5` use it here: `while number_of_guesses < max_guesses` 

Also, your last print reveals the number after the first guess already...this statement should be outside the while block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this should fix your issues:

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 100)
player_name = input("Hello, What's your name?")
number_of_guesses = 0
print('okay! '+ player_name+ ' I am guessing a number between 1 and 100:')

max_guesses = random.randint(1, 6)
print(f"You have {max_guesses} tries. ")

won = False

while number_of_guesses < max_guesses:
   guess = int(input())
   number_of_guesses += 1
   if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low")
   if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high")
   if guess == number:
        won = True
        break


if won:
    print("You guessed the number in " + str(number_of_guesses) + " tries!")
else:
    print("You did not guess the number, the number was " + str(number))
```

However, this seems like some starting-out project, so it is important to understand what every code line is doing. In case you are not sure about anything, ask away :)

Comment: Thanks alot appreciate it, it worked! If you don't mind could you explain to me what you did? Yes, ive just started python

Comment: As mentioned by me and @adam there where 2 issues with your original code. 1. You didn't use the random number generated, what simulates your dice. So I just saved it to another variable and used it to manage the number of iterations in the while loop. 2. The loosing condition was evaluated within the while block, therefore for each iteration (so already at the first one) you would print out the number.

Comment: To avoid this, I simply introduced a bool variable called `won`. Bools can either be True or False. We set it to False and start the iterations. If the number is correct, we set `won` to true and "break" out of the while loop with the `break` tag. After the loop, we only have to check if `won` is True or False and print out the corresponding messages. The answer from @adam does pretty much the same and should work as well, so it would be nice, if you set either his or my answer as the answer to your question.

Comment: In case something else is unclear, just ask away :)

Comment: Thank you guys a lot! Really helped

Comment: Would you happen to know how to save the game statistics to a file at the end of each game played?

Comment: Files aren't too difficult in python. [Have a look at this guide.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) You just need to save your stuff into a string variable and then you can save this string to file as shown in the guide.

Comment: I uploaded a new question could you take a look at that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're printing the random number, but not really using it. Could you try the following:

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 100)
player_name = input("Hello, What's your name?")
number_of_guesses = 0
print('okay! '+ player_name+ ' I am guessing a number between 1 and 100:')
min_value = 1
max_value = 6

random_number = random.randint(min_value, max_value)
print(random_number)
while number_of_guesses < random_number:
   guess = int(input())
   if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too low")
   if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too high")
   if guess == number:
        break
   number_of_guesses += 1

if guess == number:
    print("You guessed the number in " + str(number_of_guesses) + " tries!")
else:
    print("You did not guess the number, the number was " + str(number))
```

Comment: still not getting the number now the guesses allowed is less than the random number generated

Comment: You're right. There were two issues with it. I have updated it. Could you please try the updated version?

Firstly, I moved the end game conditions out of the while loop. This is because you want the program to give the results after the user attempted all tries.

Secondly, I moved the "number_of_guesses" increment to the bottom of the while loop, this is because the while loop would terminate as soon as number_of_guesses >= random_number.

Comment: what does the "f" do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to, sorry. I don't see an "f" above.

Comment: if you mean the 'f' in my answer at `print(f"You have {max_guesses} tries. ")`, this is just for string formating, so I can use the variable `max_guesses` the way I did. This is just the same as `print("You have " + str(max_guesses) + " tries. ")` and there are several other ways you could print out stuff, it just comes down to personal preference.